# Accessing vuex data by a known id

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have created a vuex store and stored several rows of data that i fetched from a remote source. The data is actually rows from a mysql table.

The data is in this format

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "property_country": "usa",
    "property_name": "i and m towers",
    "property_stars": "4",
    "property_city": "austin",
    "property_region": "texas",
    "property_type": "serviced partment",
    "date_created": "3563763673",
    "date_updated": "33377363",
    "the_user_id": "1"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "property_country": "uk",
    "property_name": "eagle towers",
    "property_stars": "5",
    "property_city": "kampala",
    "property_region": "kampala",
    "property_type": "motel",
    "date_created": "3563763673",
    "date_updated": "33377363",
    "the_user_id": "1"
},
```

I want to be able to access vuex data by id, remove by id, update by id

So far i can access `console.log(this.$store.state.properties[1].property_country);`

like that. I know the id from looping the data and so, i want to be able to use the known id to perform some mutations. What is the way to view how the data in vuex is stored and how can i access any data stored in vuex if i know the id of the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Get by Id:

```js
this.$store.state.properties.find(property => property.id == 1).property_country

// OR

getById(id) {
  this.$store.state.properties.find(property => property.id == id)
}
getById(1).property_country // "usa"
```

#### Remove by id

```js
removeById(id) {
  this.$store.state.properties.splice(this.$store.state.properties.findIndex(p=>p.id == id), 1)
}
```

#### Update by Id:

```js
updateById(id, newObject) {
  this.$store.state.properties[this.$store.state.properties.findIndex(p=>p.id == id)] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringyfy(newObject))
}
// here you have to make some logic to make sure the id still makes sense.
```

#### Update a single property

```js
this.$store.state.properties[this.$store.state.properties.findIndex(p=>p.id == 1)].property_country = "NEW_VALUE"
```

### The Vuex way

```js
// You can always get data from store using this.$store.state
// But to update, change or remove, you need mutations
mutations: {
  removeById(state, id) {
    state.properties.splice(state.properties.findIndex(p=>p.id == id), 1)
  },
  updateById(state, payload) { // payload = {id: 1, newObject = {..]}
    state.properties[state.properties.findIndex(p=>p.id == payload.id)] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringyfy(payload.newObject))
  }
}

// Use like this
this.$store.commit('removeById', 1)
this.$store.commit('updateById', {id: 1, newObject: {...}})
```

Comment: Some magic. How would i update and delete given an id and is it possible to view the contents of the entire vuex store?

Comment: @tauzN you couldn't mutate the state directly you've to pass by an action or a mutation

Comment: @Gandalf Take a look at the [build-in logger plugin](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html#built-in-logger-plugin) to see all changes to the Vuex store; it is very helpful during development

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Sure, these functions should just be in a mutation.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I shall have them there in a flash once i check out the logger.

Comment: And as @BoussadjraBrahim said, only mutate (or change) anything in the store using a mutation, else your reactivity will break. [Mutations](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html)

Comment: Yes you should define mutation and call it like `this.$store.commit("UPDATE_BY_ID",id)`

Answer (score 1):

Try out a getter with [method style access](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access)

```
getters: {
  // ...
  getPropById: (state) => (id) => {
    const {property_country}=state.properties.find(p=> p.id === id)
   
     return property_country;

  }
}
```

then use it like `this.$store.getters.getPropById(1)`

Comment: Oh nice, i can't say i paid a lot of attention to that section. How would i go about updating a row if i know the id?

Comment: you could pass the id as payload to an action that use commit to delete an item from the state